# How to select multiple images in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

Here is the grid view main page...
setting custom Adapter on GridView...
All the stuff is working correctly but i want to select multiple images...

```
gridview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview_robot_ghost);
    gridview.setAdapter(new customGridAdapter(this, GHOST_NUMBER));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Verification is Succeesfull "+ "\n Selected Ghost Position is "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
```

custom grid adapter:

```
customGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;

    private final String[] grid_values;

    public customGridAdapter(Context context,String[] grid_values)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.grid_values=grid_values;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return grid_values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            gridView=new View(context);
            gridView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)     gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            String ghost=grid_values[position];

                if (ghost.equals("Ghost1")) {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghost4);

            } else if (ghost.equals("Ghost2")) {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghost4);

            } else if (ghost.equals("Ghost3")) {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghost3);

            } else {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghost4);
            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

On `OnItemClickListener` change background of View as selected item & add the item selected into some list...

If Item is already selected, on clicking on particular item change background to normal & remove from  list

Comment: Could you please show us some example of codes? I am completly new to Android. Thank you.